# JavaScript replacing text with function result for each match in text

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace all links in a textarea element with the result of a function for that piece of the text.

Example:

```
url = /(^|<|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|>|$)/g;
Text = "Text with link inside www.stackoverflow.com";
text.replace(url, convert(RESULT));
document.write(text);

function convert(link){
  return " XX " + link + "XX";
}
```

What I need is that every link found in that string, get converted to be surrounded by XX or any other string.
The fact is that I need EACH link in the text to be sent to that function, so I can replace each of them.

I've been searching trough the web for a couple of hours. Tried a lot of stuff. Nothing works.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1. The `replace` function allows a reference to a function as its second argument. You're *calling* the `convert` function, not passing a reference.
2. The `replace` function does not modify the original string. You need to save its result.
3. You're attempting to use `convert` before it has been defined.

Putting it all together:

```
function convert(link) {
    return " XX " + link + "XX";
}
var url = /(^|<|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|>|$)/g;
var text = "Text with link inside www.stackoverflow.com";
text = text.replace(url, convert);
```

Output:

```
"Text with link inside XX www.stackoverflow.comXX"
```

Comment: Right! It works. But how to replace ALL URLs in the text?  Let's assume that the text now is: "this is a link www.stackoverflow.com.br and here is another link www.google.com".  It only replaces the first link.

Comment: @Rafael - You sure about that? Works fine for multiple links for me.

Comment: Ok, it's really working, but now I'm stuck at another problem. The function that rewrites the link executer a GET request. When I call the function, it rewrites to "undefined". I think that it rewrites before the function catches the result of the request. The entire function follows.

Comment: @Rafael - Right, your `convert` function is passed to `replace`, but then it kicks off an Ajax request, which executes asynchronously. By the time the request's callback executes, `replace` will have finished.

Comment: So... After a couple of hours, I've got it. Here's my complete function: http://pastebin.ca/2048378 Any improvements, please, let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`String#replace` doesn't modify the receiver since strings in JavaScript are immutable. You want this instead:

```
url = /(^|<|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|>|$)/g;
text = "Text with link inside www.stackoverflow.com";
text = text.replace(url, convert(RESULT));
document.write(text);

function convert(link){
  return " XX " + link + "XX";
}
```

Also, you had a reference to `Text` instead of `text` which I have corrected.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I've just wrote wrong, but that was not the problem.